# How do you set up an elastic search cluster with multiple master nodes in docker compose?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose

I have docker compose working to make a cluster of elastic search nodes with 1 master and 2 data nodes as seen below, but I'm wondering how you extend this to add more master nodes since there is still the single point of failure with this setup if the master node goes down.

More specifically, how does the second master node interact with the host & application that's using it? Do you have to bind to a different port on the host for the second master node? And then does the application have to go through a load balancer to handle the case when either of the master noes go down?

```
elasticsearch_master:
  image: elasticsearch:latest
  command: "elasticsearch -Des.cluster.name=vi -Des.node.master=true -Des.node.data=false"
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"

elasticsearch1:
  image: elasticsearch:latest
  command: "elasticsearch -Des.cluster.name=vi -Des.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch_master"
  links:
    - elasticsearch_master
  volumes:
    - "~/esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"

elasticsearch2:
  image: elasticsearch:latest
  command: "elasticsearch -Des.cluster.name=vi -Des.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch_master"
  links:
    - elasticsearch_master
  volumes:
    - "~/esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
```

Comment: Have you been able to find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

I know we're not doing it the same way but here is a code sample that worked for me.

```
services:
  esmaster1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
    container_name: esmaster1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=es_cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - "http.cors.allow-origin=*"
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=esmaster1,esmaster2"
      - "node.master=true"
      - "node.data=true"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/home/ruan/workspace/docker/elasticsearch/data

  esmaster2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
    container_name: esmaster2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=es_cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - "http.cors.allow-origin=*"
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=esmaster1,esmaster2"
      - "node.master=true"
      - "node.data=true"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/home/ruan/workspace/docker/elasticsearch/data

  elasticsearch1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
    container_name: elasticsearch1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=es_cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - "http.cors.allow-origin=*"
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=esmaster1,esmaster2"
      - "node.master=false"
      - "node.data=true"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata3:/home/ruan/workspace/docker/elasticsearch/data

  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=es_cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - "http.cors.allow-origin=*"
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=esmaster1,esmaster2"
      - "node.master=false"
      - "node.data=true"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata4:/home/ruan/workspace/docker/elasticsearch/data

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local
  esdata3:
    driver: local
  esdata4:
    driver: local
```

If the master node dies the second one takes over to be the master node and handles the cluster. If you want to use Kibana (or any other visualization tool) you should also add an other Elasticsearch instance to the cluster to handle that connection. This new instance needs not to be a master, data or ingest node.

I hope this helps!